# Switch two key bindings for every mode in Emacs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I'm not exactly sure if there is a technical term for this, but is it possible in Emacs to completely swap two sets of keybindings for all modes?  I want to make it so that regardless of mode, for example, C-t will do what C-x is supposed to do, and vice versa.  If I use the normal way of assigning a function to a keyboard shortcut, such as with `global-set-key` the binding can be overwritten by any modes that I turn on.  I feel like I read about Emacs being able to do this a long time ago, but I don't remember what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate a key or key sequence into another one early on in the input process. For example, here's how to switch `C-x` and `C-t` everywhere:

```
(define-key key-translation-map "\C-t" "\C-x")
(define-key key-translation-map "\C-x" "\C-t")
```